# MFC...How to change the name

Tags: c++, mfc, project

[image]
i cannot change the names in picture...
i want to change the titles names for the phonebook and the titles new new ...see picture.

```
CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplatePersons;
pDocTemplatePersons = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_PhoneBookTYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CPersonsDocument),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CPersonsView)
    );
if (!pDocTemplatePersons)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplatePersons);

CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_PhoneBookTYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CCitiesDocument),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CCitiesView)
    );
if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

CMultiDocTemplate* pDocPhoneTypes;
pDocPhoneTypes = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_PhoneBookTYPE,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CPhoneTypesDocument),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CPhoneTypesView)
    );
if (!pDocPhoneTypes)
    return FALSE;
AddDocTemplate(pDocPhoneTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the string resource IDR_PhoneBookTYPE you use. The name is coded in this string.

You find the description in the constructor for [CMultiDocTemplate::CMultiDocTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58d94y2f.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#cmultidoctemplate__cmultidoctemplate) and in detail in [CDocTemplate::GetDocString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0174ykw8.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#cdoctemplate__getdocstring)

Comment: now i fixed the views names...I want to change and the NEW NEW.

Comment: This are internal resources of the MFC. You can't change this resources without chaning the MFC internal resources.

Comment: how to do that to change the caption of this dialog

Comment: Alternatively you can copy the code from this small dialog from the MFC code and create your own version with your own dialog.